# Static files causing new sessions to be created

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Why does a request for a .gif image cause the session_start event to fire in my asp.net application?
In my local IIS I tried setting up a module mapping for *.gif pointing to `StaticFileModule` thinking that would prevent IIS from routing the request through asp.net, but for some reason my session start event is still firing when just requesting this single image.
Can anyone advise what needs to be set in IIS to prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to mention where exactly these gifs are. Files on disk? Blobs in the DB? Data URIs?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `modules` section within your `web.config` which has `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` set to true? This causes all requests (including .gif, .jpg, etc) to go through asp.net, not just managed ones.

Anything like this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    ...
</modules>
```

Or alternatively, have you defined any custom [`<httpHandlers>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) within your `web.config`?

It sounds like your CRM might be causing the asp.net runtime to handle the request (is it a seperate .NET app? and if so, what about it's `web.config`?)

Comment: Nope, nothing in the config file along those lines unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you may also have to disable Session State for those folders:

https://serverfault.com/questions/77852/is-it-possible-to-set-a-folder-as-cookieless-in-iis7

Comment: Unfortunately the images or folders dont exist on disk, they're stored in a CMS. I've tried adding in the path regardless into the web.config but that hasn't made a difference.

Comment: so where does the CMS store the images if not on disk? I would assume if they are coming out of the db, there is some code to do that, and that is why the StaticFileModule is not working.